# How to grep a standalone number

Tags: grep

So I have a list

number: 1
number: 2
number: 11
number: 21

and I'd like to get a line count of how many standalone number 1's there are, but my `grep 'number: 1' | wc -l` returns positive for the 11 as well. How can I tell grep to specifically get the number 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, the manual is your friend. Take a look at `man grep`.

```
-x, --line-regexp
    Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line. For a regular
    expression pattern, this is like parenthesizing the pattern and then
    surrounding it with ^ and $.
```

So you could use

```
grep -x 'number: 1' | wc -l
```

or alternatively

```
grep '^number: 1$' | wc -l
```

There's also `-c`:

```
-c, --count
    Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each
    input file. With the -v, --invert-match option (see below), count
    non-matching lines.
```

So the shortest command would be `grep -xc 'number: 1'`.